# Open Zoom Team Chat using hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, chat, zoom-sdk

I am trying to include a hyperlink that will open Zoom Team Chat in a simular way Skype does.

`<a href="skype:name lastname?call">`

Our company uses both Skype for Business and Zoom Team Chat at the moment. I can use the below to open a chat window in Skype for business

`<a href="sips:<email@domain.COM>">Skype</a>`

I can open a video Zoom call using the below:

`<a href="sip:<email@domain.COM>">Zoom</a>`

However, I cannot figure out how to open a chat in Zoom Team Chat.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom Developer Advocate here. There are two ways to get a Zoom Team Chat hyperlink:

1. Use the `channel_url`, returned from the [GET Channel API](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/chat/methods/#operation/getUserLevelChannel).
2. Use the [link to the channel](https://support.zoom.com/hc/en/article?id=zm_kb&sysparm_article=KB0059352#h_01GDP7ZHD6G2RSX19EGW309QA9), from the Zoom Team Chat user interface.

The `channel_url` (link to the channel) will be in the following format:

`https://zoom.us/launch/chat/v2/eyJzaWQiOiJleGFtcGxlamlkQGNvbmZlcmVuY2UueG1wcC56b29tLnVzIn0`

> The token on the end is an object with the `channel_jid`, base64 encoded, like `{"sid": "examplejid@conference.xmpp.zoom.us"}`.

Navigating to the `channel_url` (link to the channel) will open Zoom Team Chat to that channel.

For questions specific to the Zoom Developer Platform, feel free to ask on the [Zoom devforum](https://devforum.zoom.us/).